# Asus Zenbook UX32VD battery precharged or did I get a replacement?

Tags: laptop, battery

I'm a bit worried that my "new" Asus Zenbook UX32VD is actually a replacement. As far as I know, I should charge the battery before first use.

However, I just attached the battery after pulling the ultrabook from its plastics and the charger indicator (LED) is already green. I think "green" means that it is fully charged.

Did someone fully charge this before me (in other words, this is a replacement and not a fresh device), or does Asus precharge the Zenbook UX32VD (or UX31A) battery?

In any case, now that the lid is already green, should I still wait several hours? If so, how many?

Comment: IIRC It's not uncommon for batteries to be delivered in a charged state – probably not fully charged though. It's always better to store batteries half charged than completely empty.

Comment: To add to the given answers, it appears that I was actually given a returned product (it has a big scratch on the side of the screen). So a completely full battery does seem to be an indication of an increased chance on owning a returned product. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Li-Ion batteries are usually already charged when you receive them. Not always fully charged, but some are.
Older battery technology had to be charged for so many hours (optimally) before you used them, but that's no longer the case. If a battery is charged till green, then it's fully charged. The overly long charging time does no longer apply to modern batteries.

However, I urge you to inspect your computer thoroughly for scratch marks and so on. If there are none, there is no reason to believe you have received a pre-owned device.

Comment: Guess what.. I only just saw a rather significant scratch on the side of the screen. It seems like Asus sold me a returned product without noticing the scratch themselves. I am returning the laptop :(

Comment: I'm glad you saw it. Good luck with the return and also with your (soon to be) new product.

Answer (score 2):

From my last freshly bought laptops and mobile phones I remember the batteries have always been charged, even when all seals on the boxes etc. where okay.

Even though the indicator showed full charge, usually the battery lasted only some minutes on my new mobile phone.

If you find scratches, fingerprints etc. you should return it.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, I've bought a new UX31A and it came with zero battery charge (which is somewhat reasonable given that the battery is not user replaceable).  Thinkpads up to X61t came with at least some charge OTOH.